# Why the values from my data output as NaN when I use DataFrame for outputting a column?

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

**Pictures of my code: **
[My code/problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNeS2.png)

**Question 1:** So it's basically the title. I have a data set that I made in .xlsx format that has numeric values for things like population or area, but when I try to output a single column it shows all my values as NaN.

**Question 2:** If I get to solve this problem, how could I convert all the floats from a column into integers?

**Note:** I'm coding on Google Colaboratory.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/EW1ptlj

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. `Population` column does not exist, it's `population (2020)`, and population variable already exists (cell 308), what do you try to do in cell 309 with `df`?
2. `data['population (2020)'].astype('int')` (first verify if this column is `float` and not `str`)

Comment: 1. I though I could use population variable to storahe "Population (2020)" (I'm kinda new at coding), but now that I used just the original title it works! Thanks!

Comment: 2.  I didn't understand this answer at all, could you please explain a little bit further? (Not a native English speaker so I may need a bit more of context)

Comment: To convert a column of float to int you can use the method ".astype('int')" this is called transtyping, so once you have selected data that you want  : data['population (2020)']  you transform this series of floats to series of int with data['population (2020)'].astype('int')